# Creating your own file for your JAVA app containing informations and images (on single file only)

Tags: java, image, makefile

Situation: I've created a (JAVA) journal app which you can write your own journal and put images to the context.

Problem: Now I'm trying to create a file containing all the informations including text, images and settings. I want to save it on a SINGLE file only. I've tried so many things like Converting Image to binary object and appending it to the file, Serialization, BufferedImage. But whenever i try to read the file, i can't get the image back. only the texts.

Concept: On microsoft word we can make a document, we can write text and put images then we save it to a single file with ".docx" extension.

Is there any way to implement this concept to my app?

Comment: You need to come up with a document format, like (block type 1 = TEXT or BITMAP) (data block) (block type 2  = TEXT or BITMAP) (data block 2)  (data block 3 = ... ) **or** save as a zip archive of (HTML text file + image files) .  For the block type format you could keep a collection of objects and serialize / deserialize them.

Comment: MS `docx` are actually zip files.  You could consider following a similar concept

Comment: First of all create file for text and files for images and finally files for settings and at last zip them using a java class in util package

Comment: Also Jar files are just Zip files, and Java has classes for both (`java.util.jar.JarFile` and `java.util.zip.ZipFile` respectively).